# Accessing Google Maps Navigation from Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I'm completely stuck. I am trying to use an Intent to pass an EditText value to Google Maps to use outside of my app. I have the basic syntax that I need, but not sure where I pass in the address. I'm wanting to use a regular address and not latitude/longitude.

The code I have to launch Google Maps is

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=address"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And my XML for the value that I want passed in...

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/routeButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:text="Route"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

I'm just wanting to take the text that is input in the address's EditText box and put into Google Maps Navigation as the destination using my current location upon clicking the "Route" button. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract the string from the EditText and attach it to the Uri like this:

```
String map = "http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=" + yourAddress;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(map));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to return to the activity upon arriving at the destination? Or could point me in the right direction? Thank you! -

Comment: If you aren't explicitly calling `finish()` on the activity you should just be able to use the back button or up button. Otherwise your app will still be running, you can return to it the same as you would any other app.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks a lot for your help!